# Laravel 5.4 Call to a member function attach() on null while inserting in pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, pivot-table, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I get some problem while inserting my data in pivot table.
when I use return `dd($request->education);` I've successfully get the array.

But when I use attach

> foreach($request->education as $education)
>           {
>               $preq->education()->attach([
>                   'education_id' => $education
>               ]);
>           }

or

> $preq->education()->attach([
>               'education_id' => $request->education
>           ]);

Get some error `Call to a member function attach() on null`

Here is my Preq model

```
class Preq extends Model {  
    protected $table = 'preqs';

    public function education()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany(Education::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing the `return` statement. And make sure you add a use statement with the path to Education class: `use App\Education`. You should also close this as solved.

Answer (score 4):

To chain you would need to return the object back from `education()`

```
class Preq extends Model {  
    protected $table = 'preqs';

    public function education()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Education::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Comment: got some error like this `SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'SD' for column 'education_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `education_preq` (`created_at`, `education_id`, `preq_id`, `updated_at`) values (2017-12-13 07:30:53, SD, 12, 2017-12-13 07:30:53))`

Comment: Try: `return $this->belongsToMany(Education::class, 'preqs')->withTimestamps();`